# insert all rows of datagridview into sql server database

Tags: sql-server, datagridview

I am trying to insert all the rows of a datagridview into a database table. Below is my code and error message snapshot. Could plz tell me where m going wrong.
I tried placing the for loop at different sections of the code, at one point the rows were inserted successfully in the table but still the error message was there.

```
 Private Sub addnewclasses()

    Dim open As String = db.OpenDB
    If open <> "OK" Then
        MessageBox.Show("Error openining the database check the connection path to your database:", "POS", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        Exit Sub
    End If

    For i As Integer = 0 To DGV_Class.Rows.Count - 1

        Dim AirlineCode As String = DGV_Airline.Rows(0).Cells(0).Value
        Dim ClassCode As String = DGV_Class.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value
        Dim ClassDesc As String = DGV_Class.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value
        Dim ClassSort As Integer = DGV_Class.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value
        Dim ClassBook As Boolean = DGV_Class.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value

        '========================================================================
        airline.setairlinecode(AirlineCode)
        airline.setClassCode(ClassCode)
        airline.setClassDesc(ClassDesc)
        airline.setClassSort(ClassSort)
        airline.setClassBooking(ClassBook)
        '========================================================================
    Next
    Try
        If Not airline.insert_class_master(db, True) Then
            MessageBox.Show("Error occurred while adding new airline to the system make sure the information your provided is correct!", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
            Exit Sub
        End If

        MessageBox.Show("New airline has been added to the system successfully", "system Updated successfully", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)


    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End Try
```

## End Sub

```
Public Function insert_class_master(ByVal dbaccesscl As databaselogic, ByVal save As Boolean) As Boolean
    Try
        Dim SQL As String = "insert into Tbl_Class_Master ( " & _
                                         "Airline_Code, " & _
                                         "Class_Code, " & _
                                         "Class_Description, " & _
                                         "Class_Sorting, " & _
                                         "Class_Booking) values " & _
                                        "(@0,@1,@2,@3,@4)"
        dbaccesscl.ExecuteSQL(SQL, Me.AirlineCode, Me.ClassCode, Me.ClassDesc, Me.Classsort, Me.Classbooking)

        If save Then
            dbaccesscl.Commit()
        End If
        Return True
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString, "error from inserting")
        dbaccesscl.Rollback()
        Return False
    End Try
End Function
```

> The parameterized query'(@0 nvarchar(2),@1 nvarchar(4000),@2 nvarchar(4000),@3 int, @4 bit expects the parameters '@1', which was not supplied.

Comment: maybe Me.ClassCode is null?

Comment: No Me.ClassCode is not null, as I am reading the data for this particular parameter in my sub addnewclasses(). And the same is supplied to parameterized query.

Comment: I changed my above code to the following, but still m getting the same error message. Anybody out there to solve this.

Comment: i guess you should provide more information ... what is databaselogic? what happens in ExecuteSQL?

Comment: databaselogic is a class in my project, and executesql is sub in databaselogic class which executes sql commands like commit and rollback.

Comment: ... and executesql probably creates the sqlcommand and adds the parameters etc ... so my guess is the error is in that function ... maybe you should post that code ...

Comment: Public Sub ExecuteSQL(ByVal SQL As String, ByVal ParamArray Obj() As Object)

        ' build the command object
        Dim CMD As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(SQL, Me.connectionobject, Me.transactionobject)

        ' add the parameters to the sql command
        Dim I As Integer
        For I = 0 To Obj.Length - 1
            CMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@" & I, Obj(I))
        Next

        ' run the sql
        CMD.ExecuteNonQuery()

    End Sub

Comment: Hello, I found a solution for this. As I am accepting 'N' number of rows from user to input in a datagridview, and every time a row is entered with some data a new is created, and that is the blank row which was giving error. I modified my For loop as follows. For i As Integer = 0 To DGV_Class.Rows.Count - 2. and this worked for me. Though i understand that this is not the best solution but things are working as desired. Thanks and Regards